# Message (ConstPtr) forwarding in ROS

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am developing an application with several nodes: one receives a message (for example: ImageConstPtr&) that will be forwarded to another node in particular (via another topic), following a pool of workers approach. Can I create a publisher that use its function publish() with that ConstPtr& message, or should I transfer its contents to a new message object?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65199/message-(constptr)-forwarding-in-ros/) by [Javier J. Salmerón García](https://answers.ros.org/users/4037/javier-j.-salmer%C3%B3n-garc%C3%ADa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short version:

Yes, you can pass that ConstPtr to a call to publish(), and it will work.

Long answer: Can you explain the problem you're trying to solve in a bit more detail? I'm envisioning a sort of round-robin message dispatch, and that seems painful.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2013-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2